# Dynamically check connection string for different Database

Tags: ssis

Perhaps my post title not very appropriate but I'm not very sure how I name it. Anyway, I recently got a legacy SSIS package which is using FoxPro DB. But now it is decided to take away FoxPro and bring SQL Server (experimental). So,let me describe what I have so far

I have three FoxPro connection strings in my DEV environment (from different warehouses). These three connection strings are the main source of my data. These connection strings are listed in a SLQ Server table say table name is `dbo.Source`. Now the SSIS package is designed in such a way that it can collect those connection strings from the `dbo.source` table and loop through each connection string using a `Foreach Loop Container` in control flow and it is assigned to a variable say `DataSource`, then the current value of the variable `DataSource` is used as connection string in `OLE DB Connection Manager`. Then in the data flow the `OLE DB Connection Manager` is used in the data flow source.

Now one of the connection string in the `dbo.source` has changed to SQL Server data source and remaining two are same as FoxPro. Now when the loop runs and the `OLE DB Connection Manager` an SQL Server connection string (as because it is FoxPro provider) it throws error. So I want to do such that I can change the `OLE DB Connection Manager` settings dynamically depends upon different type of connection strings coming from `dbo.source` table (well, I'm identifying it in a script task). This might sounds ridiculous but I'm just hoping to find some way to do it. Almost forgot to mention I'm using SQL Server Business Intelligence 2008 if it any matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using a script task, why not create a new string or int variable and set its value to 1 or 0 depending on the type of connection identified in the script task?

Next, create two separate data flow tasks, one for FoxPro and one for SQL, then connect them via conditional expression constraints to the script task.
That way, the correct path will be followed.

Answer (score 1):

The approach to set connection strings in a loop is probably a lot more pain than it is worth and is really fighting the way that SSIS was intended to be used.  Consider this:

- Create two connection managers - one for fox pro and one for SQL
- create data flows for each table and hook them up with the correct
  connection managers
- use a package configuration (i.e. SQL table) to configure the
  connection strings
- If there are a lot of tables and this seems like a lot of work, use
  BIML to generate the package(s)

The benefits of using the standard approach is that it is more maintainable, because it is what is expected.  A new person working on the project will be able to jump right in.  Additionally, the metadata can be validated, so you have the added benefit of knowing that things will work before you begin execution.